# Json schema variable properties

Tags: jsonschema

Based some condition my IPV4 can have either 2 or 3 properties but those are required. How to define it. I tried below schema. I get error saying "JSON is valid against more than one schema from 'oneOf'. Valid schema indexes: 0, 1"

```
"IPv4Type": {
    "type": "object",
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "properties": {
                "provider-address": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "ipv4"
                },
                "customer-address": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "ipv4"
                },
                "mask": {
                    "type": "number"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "provider-address",
                "customer-address",
                "mask"
            ]
        },
        {
            "properties": {
                "provider-address": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "ipv4"
                },
                "mask": {
                    "type": "number"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "provider-address",
                "mask"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is the condition?  How the problem is solved depends on whether the condition is the value of a field or the presence of a field.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas:

- you can drop the `oneOf` , define your JSON in one object, with all 3 properties defined, but adding only  "provider-address" and "mask" as required
- defining `"additionalProperties": false` the the 2nd definition under `oneOf`
- replacing `oneOf` with `anyOf`